# Why can't I get more than 30 cells in a table?

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I try to get data from more than 30 cells (if I'm not mistaken, about 40), but all the time I get no more than 30. How to solve this issue?

- In Case 9 - ok
- In Case 10 - failure.

Rows has 30 items, but I select much more

```
namespace CBox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "CBox";

        static String spreadsheetId = "1LovVHkHGQYADfgEBMGEaZFTDkSgQEQhQ-FuRZHWkXHo";
        String range;
        static String credPath = "token.json";
        static FileStream stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request;

        static UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        SheetsService service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });


        private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            comboBox2.Items.Clear();

            range = "A2:AT9";
            request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);
            //request.MajorDimension = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest.MajorDimensionEnum.COLUMNS;
            ValueRange response = request.Execute();
            IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;

            switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
            {
                ***********

                case 9:                                                     //120
                    foreach (var rows in values)
                    {
                        if (rows[28] != "" && rows[29] != "")
                        {
                            comboBox2.Items.Add(rows[0]);
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 10:                                                     //130
                    foreach (var rows in values)
                    {
                        if (rows[30] != "" && rows[31] != "")
                        {
                            comboBox2.Items.Add(rows[0]);
                        }
                    }
                    break;


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another excel issue.  Excel to save space has a used range for each worksheet.  So it looks like you are returning from worksheet the used range which is only 30 columns.  Then you are trying to add add beyond the 30 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google cuts the rows strictly according to the content.

Let's say you have a table in Google Sheets:

```
[dsds] [dwdw] []
[dswg] [] []
[dswf] [] [dwdw]
```

If you make a request for the specified range (A0:C2), then looking at the values in VisualStudio during debugging, you will see that there are not three elements in each row, but exactly as many as needed. Any extra empty cells ARE NOT AUTOMATICALLY UPLOADED.

```
[dsds] [dwdw]
[dswg]
[dswf] [] [dwdw]
```

I didn't take this into account. I compared the value with the index in the string, which in fact does not exist, although in theory this cell was in the requested range.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that all cells in the range have value? The maximum range of cells containing a value will be returned. So if you some empty values at the end of the range, they will not be returned.

Edit..
I tried to get the range from the sheet you posted in the comments, no problem.

```
{"majorDimension":"ROWS","range":"'????1'!A9:AT9","values":[["Prime Grand 2835 3 Lens","74","15","180","0,72","160","75","Cool White","http://tdkatod.ru/1497","","","","","","100","75","110","80","130","90","140","100","150","115","160","125","170","130","180","140","190","150","200","160","210","170","220","180","230","190","240","220"]],"ETag":null}
```

[Try for yourself](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get?apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%221LovVHkHGQYADfgEBMGEaZFTDkSgQEQhQ-FuRZHWkXHo%22%2C%22range%22%3A%22A9%3AAT9%22%7D)

Which API version are you using? If you try the code (C#) on the Google API page it just works.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LovVHkHGQYADfgEBMGEaZFTDkSgQEQhQ-FuRZHWkXHo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I didn`t change anything. I try to parse value till 190 , but it fails at 120. I`ll try to fill other cells with zeros, but don`t know if it helps

Comment: And if i try to serialize array of values with JsonConvert to see all array together, i got the same 30 values, not more

Comment: Use v4 API on C#, will try to copy/paste code from this site and see if it works, thanks

Comment: Look at this, I didn’t change any parameters, the same range, the same document

If i write 


            ValueRange response = request.Execute();
            IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;
            var row = values;
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject (row))

I see all cells in the book, but if i write 

     Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject (row[31]))

I got error

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛяшенко, could you answer your opening question? In case the solution is relevant to other people as well.